# Is font-face worth it if it has to call multiple files anyway?

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

So a cross-browser @font-face solution requires multiple HTTP requests, it seems.  This is the best code I've been able to find:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Graublau Web';
  src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
  src: local('Graublau Web Regular'), local('Graublau Web'),
    url("GraublauWeb.woff") format("woff"),
    url("GraublauWeb.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("GraublauWeb.svg#grablau") format("svg");
}
```

For that matter am I better off just using Javascript or will that slow down loading times just as much?  Is my ultimate solution for loading speeds (and thus SEO, which is my priority) going to be using images?

Thanks!

Comment: Search engines usually don't follow stylesheet rules, IIRC.

Comment: @Zeta I think you should understand it as if the special font cases was replaced by images then what about SEO?

Comment: What makes you assume that above code causes multiple http requests? At a glance I see no reason why it would require that.

Answer (score 1):

The browser will only make one connection and one download based on that rule. That rule does not tell the browser to download all the fonts specified - that wouldn't make sense. Rather it tells the browser to download the first specified font it finds.

The line:

```
src: url('GraublauWeb.eot');
```

is in a separate rule because the browser that the line targets (IE) doesn't support alternate font list. This exploits the fact that browsers will ignore css rules that they don't understand.